# Tcpdump with -w writing gibberish to file

Tags: bash, shell, redhat, tcpdump

When trying to capture tcpdump output to a file, I get the following:

▒ò▒▒▒▒3▒X▒▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒Xu<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒D<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒D<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X5▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b
7
7▒▒3▒X▒<<▒▒▒▒▒▒▒4▒4▒b

If I run tcpdump without the -w the output displays fine in the shell.

Here is the input:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -Z root -w `date '+%m-%d-%y.%T.pcap'`
```

Comment: That's a pcap file, not text. Display it using `tcpdump -r` or open it in wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tcpdump -w` writes the raw file, which is not meant for reading directly. You can read the file back with the `tcpdump -r` option as suggested in the man page:

> -r     Read packets from file (which was created with the -w option).  Standard input is used if file is ‘‘-’’.
>
> -w     Write the raw packets to file rather than parsing and printing them out.  They can later be printed with the -r option.  Standard output is used  if  file  is  ‘‘-’’.   See pcap-savefile(5) for a description of the file format.

Another option would be to redirect the output without using the -w option:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -Z root > `date '+%m-%d-%y.%T.pcap'`
```

But if I remember correctly you don’t get exactly what would be written with the `-w` option.